# NSCameraUsageDescription needed for C++ projects in Xcode for MacOS Mojave

Tags: c++, xcode, macos-mojave

I am trying to run OpenCV projects in Xcode and it seems like there's a new need to provide an info.plist for C++ applications NSCameraUsageDescription.

```
2018-09-28 00:03:15.181948+0800 k_nearest_detector_v2[23505:710470] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

How do I go about creating a .plist file for a C++ project as it has never been needed before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a solution. Put the file with the desired NSCameraUsageDescription, NSMicrophoneUsageDescription (or others) with the assembled file from XCode (See screen shots below). For the Release and Debug versions.
[image: Products-> Right Click-> Show in Finder]
[image: "Info.plist"]

Comment: Hmmm anyway to generate an info.plist for the project tho. Or can we just use a generic one generated from other macOS swift projects?

Comment: @lw803, you can create a new **"Property List"** from the "Resource" for MacOS or use a file from another project by deleting unnecessary fields. This is just a file with keys and values.

Answer (score 9):

You can even automate the steps described by @Valery Gromov. Just copy the file in the Build Phases. Uncheck the `Copy only when installing` checkbox to be able to run it directly from Xcode.
[image: Copy Info.plist]