# Info.plist added but Xcode still crashing

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I'm setting up a project utilizing `OpenCV` and `Xcode` and I want to open up the webcam using VideoCapture. I have added my own `Info.plist` file (as a command-line project in C++ doesn't have an Info.plist) and I have added it to the project under targets/general/identity. My info.plist is verified as OK from the command `"plutil Info.plist"`.

I also have the "`Pre-Process Info.plist`" tag under "`Packaging`" changed to "`yes`". However, I still get this error:

> "This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
>   an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data."

I have tried many StackOverFlow links and they have all failed, including this one: [Accessing webcam in Xcode with OpenCV (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190412/accessing-webcam-in-xcode-with-opencv-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If I don't add the Info.plist file to finder (the link at the bottom of the link), I get the same error.

When I add it to finder along with the executable, I get this error along with the previous error:

> "There was an error parsing the Info.plist for the bundle at URL"

Please let me know how I can fix this. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: If the below answer solved your issue, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some text (Usage Description) in Info.plist for key "`NSCameraUsageDescription`". Otherwise, the app will crash when app access Camera. Please see the snapshot below.

[image]

Hope it helps. Otherwise, please let us know.

Comment: My Info.plist has NSCameraUsageDescription and the one for microphone as well. (Written exactly has you have it)

Comment: Please check XCode project Build settings for info.plist file. The location of plist file should be correctly updated under Packaging in Build Settings.